# Passing data to modal with $('#MyModal').modal('show');

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Dygraphs is a plugin that allows you to easily turn json into charts in an HTML page.  From with a dygraphs chart, I am able to annotate the chart, and the annotations can have a clickHandler event:

```
annotations.push({
    series:  "@Model.Project.id_project",
    x: date,
    shortText: "X",
    text: message,
    cssClass: "annotation",
    clickHandler: function(annotation, point, dygraph, event) {
        $('#ChangeOrderModal').modal('show');  //<<<<<------------------------
    }
});
```

This line:

```
$('#ChangeOrderModal').modal('show');
```

Does a good job of opening this modal:

```
<div id="ChangeOrderModal" class="modal hide fade">
<div class="modal-body">
    This is a test
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
</div>
```

But, I need to pass some data into this modal, and I'm not sure how to do this.  For the sake of simplicity, let's just say it's a string:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    This is a test.  String passed in: ______
</div>
```

From the annotation where I open modal, how would I pass in a string?  And how would I display it in the modal?

Thanks!

Comment: can you directly access the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some element in your modal to hold the data:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  This is a test. String passed in: <span id="passed-in-string"></span>
</div>
```

And then simply set the element's value before showing the modal:

```
clickHandler: function(annotation, point, dygraph, event) {
  var stringToPass = 'Something';
  $('#passed-in-string').html(stringToPass);
  $('#ChangeOrderModal').modal('show');  //<<<<<------------------------
}
```